# Pandas read_sql() doesn't like DISTINCT keyword when using hive odbc connector

Tags: sql, pandas, hadoop, hive, pyodbc

I am accessing hive through a pyodbc connection. It uses the Hortonworks Hive ODBC driver. I am using pandas to read the sql results into a dataframe. There are some queries that work and some that don't. I can't figure out why. For example,

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=HiveConnection;UID=username;PWD=password;', autocommit=TRUE)
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM myTable AS m WHERE m.file = 'myfile';", con=conn)
```

returns everything just fine. However, when I run this

```
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT DISTINCT m.file FROM myTable AS m;", con=conn)
```

or this

```
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT m.file, count(m.file) FROM myTable AS m GROUP BY m.file;", con=conn)
```

it gives me an error.

```
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Hortonworks][HiveODBC] (35) Error from Hive: error code: '0' error message: 'ExecuteStatement finished with operation state: ERROR_STATE'. (35) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

I found this https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/error-from-hive-executestatement-finished-connecting-to-hadoop-table which addresses a similar issue in Tableau. It mentions that the problem is most likely with user permissions. I don't think that is the issue because I can run some queries but not others. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select *` fetch tasks don't require MapReduce jobs. The issue could be that the cluster being queried requires a queue that you have permissions to execute the MapReduce job.

Try setting the queue to one that you know you have permissions to.

For TEZ tasks

```
pd.read_sql("set tez.queue.name=<your_queue_name>;", con=conn)
```

For MapReduce tasks

```
pd.read_sql("set mapreduce.job.queuename=<your_queue_name>;" , con=conn)
pd.read_sql("set mapreduce.job.queue=<your_queue_name>;" , con=conn)
```